# Initial orientation of UICollectionView (iOS 8)

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, orientation

I have an iOS 8 project (no autolayout) with a UICollectionView with 4 items in it arranged horizontally.  When I start my app in landscape mode, the collection view is still in portrait mode.  When the device is rotated, the collection view correctly rotates.

willRotateToInterfaceOrientation and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation are not called for the initial display.  Only viewDidLoad and viewWillLayoutSubviews are called.

Comment: Are you nesting view controllers, like a regular UIViewController that has a UICollectionViewController in it? Are all the other UI items rotated correctly?

Comment: Just a UIViewController with a UICollectionView as a subview of it's view.

Comment: I also tried adding a UICollectionViewController as a child of the UIViewController.  Removing it's view (UICollectionView) from the superview and adding it to the UIViewController's view.  Same results.

Comment: I also tried just a simple UIView and UIViewController (simpler case) and am running into the problem.  I am testing it on an iPhone 6+.